# Populate a Combobox inside a datagrid

Tags: python, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to populate a combobox inside a WPF datagrid.
The Xaml is this one

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="objects"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="91" Margin="96,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" RenderTransformOrigin="0.581,0.499">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Object Name" Binding="{Binding objName}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dataGridComboBoxColumn"  Header="Material" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=SelectedAwaitingItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto" TextBinding="{x:Null}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

and the code is

```
class objects(object):
  def __init__(self, objName,Items):
      self.objName = objName
      self.SelectedAwaitingItem = ""
      self.Items = Items    


    gridUnknownDocs = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(self, 'objects')
    item = []
    politetitles = {
    1 : ('Mr' ), 
    2 : ('Ms'),
    3 : ('Mrs'), 
    4 : ('Sir'),
    }


    item.append(objects("Cube",["3" "2"]))
    item.append(objects("Square",["1" "2"]))
    gridUnknownDocs.ItemsSource = item
```

I'm able to see the textbox populated correctly (with Cube and Square values) but the combobox appears always empty
Any suggestion on what I'm missing?
Thanks
Max

Answer (score 1):

Any property ending in path is expecting a string which is a name of a property.
You have a binding for selectedvaluepath.
I don't follow what items actually contains but you need to tell it which property is the value and which to display.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26347.wpf-combobox-binding-in-datagrid.aspx

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks. you are correct, I was using the selectedvaluepath instead of selectedvaluebinding but I'm still not able to add a simple list of 2 values the combobox and I don't get any error from VS (it simily doesn't fill the list). I thin that I'm doing something wrong in python code to correctly flll the value of Itemssource. Do you have a simple example to share?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would bind the `ItemsSource` property of a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to a property of a visual ancestor:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="Material" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=SelectedAwaitingItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto" TextBinding="{x:Null}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```